# Remove NaN from 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, nan, array-broadcasting

For example, if I have the 2D array as follows.

```
[[1,2,3,NAN],
 [4,5,NAN,NAN],
 [6,NAN,NAN,NAN]
]
```

The desired result is

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5],
 [6]
]
```

How should I transform?

I find using
 `x = x[~numpy.isnan(x)]` can only generate [1,2,3,4,5,6], which has been squeezed into one dimensional array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just apply that `isnan` on a row by row basis

```
In [135]: [row[~np.isnan(row)] for row in arr]
Out[135]: [array([1., 2., 3.]), array([4., 5.]), array([6.])]
```

Boolean masking as in `x[~numpy.isnan(x)]` produces a flattened result because, in general, the result will be ragged like this, and can't be formed into a 2d array.

---

The source array must be float dtype - because `np.nan` is a float:

```
In [138]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3,np.nan],[4,5,np.nan,np.nan],[6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]])
In [139]: arr
Out[139]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3., nan],
       [ 4.,  5., nan, nan],
       [ 6., nan, nan, nan]])
```

If `object` dtype, the numbers can be integer, but `np.isnan(arr)` won't work.

If the original is a list, rather than an array:

```
In [146]: alist = [[1,2,3,np.nan],[4,5,np.nan,np.nan],[6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]]
In [147]: alist
Out[147]: [[1, 2, 3, nan], [4, 5, nan, nan], [6, nan, nan, nan]]
In [148]: [[i for i in row if ~np.isnan(i)] for row in alist]
Out[148]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

---

The flat array could be turned into a list of arrays with `split`:

```
In [152]: np.split(arr[~np.isnan(arr)],(3,5))
Out[152]: [array([1., 2., 3.]), array([4., 5.]), array([6.])]
```

where the `(3,5)` split parameter could be determined by counting the non-nan in each row, but that's more work and doesn't promise to be faster than than the row iteration.